# How to write an if else statement referencing which button (of multiples) was clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, button, click

I am writing a multiple choice quiz.  As it stands now, I have managed to identify which button is clicked by the user.  I'm now trying to write an if else statement based on that information.  Each question will have a different button represent the right answer, so ideally I'd like something like "if id of button clicked !== correct, this, else this."  I've provided some of the code to give you an idea of where I'm trying to go with this.  All help appreciated!

```
//h1 will display the questions
var quiz = [
    //quiz questions and potential answers here in this array
    Question1 = {
        question: "this is question 1",
        //these will probably be changed into buttons
        answer1: "wrong answer",
        answer2: "wrong answer",
        answer3: "right answer",
        answer4: "wrong answer",
        correct: "answer3"
        
    },
    Question2 = {
        question: "this is question 2",
        //these will probably be changed into buttons
        answer1: "wrong answer",
        answer2: "right answer",
        answer3: "wrong answer",
        answer4: "wrong answer",
        correct: "answer2"
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
            allButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.clear();
                console.log("you clicked: ", this.innerHTML);
            });
```

For reference, in this case, "answer1," answer2," etc correspond with the ids of the buttons

Comment: Please include some of your HTML as well

Comment: You can use `this.id` to get the clicked button's id: `if (this.id === currentQuestion.correct) …`.

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as I understand your situation, you want to generate some buttons dynamically  which depens on the question, right? I've managed to built something like this, I don't know if this could solve your problem, at least it can give you some insights...

So basically we've got a simple HTML document, which includes only a root div and the question, the question is hardcoded but focus on the logic behind in the JS part:

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
      <h1>Which one is the blablablababla?</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

And this is how we generate buttons depens on information we give it, you can add questions in this array or maybe create an object and give it two arrays one contains questions and other the answers:

```
const buttonsInfo = [
  { name: 'answer one', type: 'wrong answer' },
  { name: 'answer two', type: 'wrong answer' },
  { name: 'answer three', type: 'right answer' },
  { name: 'answer four', type: 'wrong answer' },
];

const generateButton = (arrayOfButtons) => {
  const buttons = arrayOfButtons.map((item) => {
    const button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    button.innerHTML = item.name;
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(item.type);
    });
    return button;
  });
  return buttons;
};

const generatedButtons = generateButton(buttonsInfo);
const root = document.getElementById('root');

for (let i = 0; i < generatedButtons.length; i++) {
  root.appendChild(generatedButtons[i]);
}
```

[image: This is how it looks on the browser]